# Find maximum balanced subarray

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a character parenthesis array and an integer array.

We need to find the maximum sum sub-array in the integer array such that the corresponding sub-array in the character array has balanced parenthesis.
Formally, a balanced parentheses is subset of { [,],{,},<,>,(,) }∗ defined recursively as follows:

```
The empty string is balanced parentheses.
If A is balanced parentheses, then so are the strings [A], {A} , <A>, (A).
If A and B are balanced parenthesis, then so is the string AB.
```

Let N=4 and character array be : ()() and integer array be -1 -2 3 4 then answer is 7 as  last 2 elements: 3 + 4 = 7.

How to find maximum sum for given character array and integer array ?

I am currently checking maximum sub array and then checking if its balanced or not and continuing it till i get balanced one. But this is inefficient. Is their any efficient way as N <=10^5

Answer (score 2):

Using a [push down automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton), you can create find all the places where he parentheses are balanced. This will be a series of indices `i_1,i_2,...,i_k`. Assuming the array is balanced itself, `i_k = n-1` (0 based indices).

The above can be done in linear time.

Using the above, you can crate an auxillary array, defined as:

```
aux[k] = intArray[i_(k-1) + 1] + intArray[i_(k-1) + 2] + ... + intArray[i_(k)-1] + intArray[i_k]
```

In words: the element `k` is the sum of elements from element `i_(k-1)` (exclusive) until `i_k` (inclusive). (`i_0` is defined as `i_0=-1` for simplifying things).

The above is an array containing all sums with corresponding balanced parentheses , and you can now invoke the "regular" maximum sum algorithm on `aux`, to find the answer.

The proof of correctness will be based on the fact that each set of balanced parentheses (including the optimal one) is a candidate to the max subarray algorithm, and every subarray in `aux` is a balanced parentheses series.

pseudo code:

Assuming existence of `findMaxSubArray(arr)` that returns "regular" maximum sub array algorithm:

```
stack s = new Stack()
cands= new list
cands.add(-1)
for (int i = 0; i < parantheses.length; i++)
   if parantheses[i] == '(' ||  parantheses[i] == '[' || parantheses[i] == '{':
       stack.push(parantheses[i]) 
       continue
   if stack.peek() == '(' && parantheses[i] == ')':
       stack.pop() //remove head of stack
   else if stack.peek() == '[' && parantheses[i] == ']':
      stack.pop()
   //similar line for '}'
   if stack.isEmpty(): //found balanced subarray
        cands.add(i)
//at this point we have a list cands containing ends of all valid parantheses.
//we now wish to make aux of the corresponding sums
int[] aux = new int[cands.length - 1];
for (int i = 1; i<aux.length; i++)
     start = cands.get(i-1)
     end = cands.get(i)
     aux[i-1] = 0
     for (int j = start+1; j<= end; j++):
        aux[i-1] += intsArray[j];
     //when done, aux[i-1] is the sum of balances parantheses cands_{i-1} until cands_i
//we have established our aux array
return findMaxSubArray(aux)
```

Comment: Any psuedocode or code in C++ or java will make things more clear. Am not getting all of it.

Comment: Just tell me how to make auxilliary array. Remaining finding maximum sum subarray i understand

Comment: @user3840069 I added a java-like pseudo code that tries to explain it. The idea is to use pushdown automaton first to find the correct indices, and then just iterate to find the sum for each index in aux.

Comment: why you are taking only i and i-1 ??? In above example your cands will be -1 1 3 righ ?

Comment: @user3840069 I am not going to answer your questions if you intend to delete the question anyway, I spent time for answering it and help the community - and will not agree on making my hard work go in vain. Understand the algorithm I proposed and implementation will be easy.

Comment: Ok am sorry for my mistake